# Flutter 2.0 Migration : _InternalLinkedHashMap<String,String?> is not a subtype of type Map<String,String>? in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to migrate my application to Flutter 2.0. I already make the transition. But now, I have multiple error on my API call. Before the migration, everything was working fine.

Here is an example of these error when I'm trying to get articles from my API. I have a JsonWebToken to secure my calls.

[image]

One more time, before the migration, everything was working well. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at the signatures:

```
_InternalLinkedHashMap<String,String?>
                   Map<String,String>?
```

Meaning `headerJWT` requires the second type parameter to be nullable.

This will work:

```dart
void main() {
  final Map<String, String?> foo = {};
  foo as Map<String, String?>?;
}
```

But this won't:

```dart
void main() {
  final Map<String, String?> foo = {};
  foo as Map<String, String>?;
}
```